# Setting the "binwidth" in ggplot histogram with POSIXct / datetime values (geom_histogram)

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I'm trying to understand the behaviour of `binwith` in `geom_histogram()` when running over POSIXct / datetime values. In [the documentation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_histogram.html), it says that `binwith` specifies *the width of the bins* which *can be specified as a numeric value* and that *the bin width of a date variable is the number of days in each time*. So I would expect the following two `ggplot` commands to produce the same output.

Not only is this not the case, but the second command takes about 5 minutes to run

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(day = as.POSIXct("2018-11-01 10:00:00")+(1:10)*3600*24)


ggplot(df,aes(day)) + 
  geom_histogram(bins = 10,colour = "black",fill = "grey")
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(df,aes(day)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 1,colour = "black",fill = "grey")
```

[image]

Created on 2018-11-04 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had the rubber duck experience and found that the with *date* [the documentation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_histogram.html) meant specifically an vector of the class `Date`. The behaviour of `binwidth`with the class `POSIXct` is described in the followup sentence: *the bin width of a time variable is the number of **seconds**.*

In short, the solution is multiplying `binwidth` by `3600*24` to get days instead of seconds.

```
ggplot(df,aes(day)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 1*3600*24,colour = "black",fill = "grey")
```